# Как сложить словари в цикле

Tags: python, циклы, словари

Есть код, который перебирает один список для другого, преобразуя все это в словари.

```
all_colors = ["black", "silver", "gray", "white", "maroon", "red", "purple"]
all_models = ["Audi RS2", "Vauxhall Ampera", "Dacia Duster", "Lamborghini Gallardo"]

h = {}
for i in all_models:
    for k in all_colors:
        d = {i: k}
        h.update(d)
print(h)
```

Дело в том, что на выходе я получаю

```
>>> {'Audi RS2': 'purple', 'Vauxhall Ampera': 'purple', 'Dacia Duster': 'purple', 'Lamborghini Gallardo': 'purple'}
```

Хотя, по идее, должно быть так

```
>>> {'Audi RS2': 'black', 'Audi RS2': 'silver', ... 'Vauxhall Ampera': 'black', 'Vauxhall Ampera': 'silver' и т.д.}
```

Когда прописываю print(d) внутри цикла, то все хорошо, словари формируются как надо, осталось только соединить, но update соединяет почему-то только последний цвет в списке для каждой машины другого списка. Прошу помощи с этим у вас, как исправить?

Comment: ключ должен быть один, вы хотите получить несколько одних и тех же.

Comment: т.е. нельзя сделать то, что я бы хотел?

Comment: все, я понял смысл, спасибо!

Comment: по идее как раз не должно быть так, потому что на каждую итерацию внешнего цикла внутренний цикл проходит целиком. Т.е. получается каждый цвет с каждой маркой.

Comment: Ключи в словаре уникальны, они не могут повторяться.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте zip для одновременного перебора двух (и более коллекций):

```
>>> for item in zip([1, 2, 3], ['sugar', 'spice', 'everything nice']):
...     print(item)
...
(1, 'sugar')
(2, 'spice')
(3, 'everything nice')
```